# Angular 7/NgRX back-end authentication at initialization (initialization effect)

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have an angular application that is using NgRX store, as part of this store I have the user profile and authentication status.  The application is working fine at all ends. When the application loads, a service is called that reads the access_key from local storage and connects to the back-end endpoint to validate the access_key and responds with the user profile. I dispatch an action that sets the user and authentication.

However, I realized that  this is happening too late. When a user lands on any route that is protected by a guard the first state of authenticated is false.

**I would like to move my method from the service to an effect that runs at the initiation before any *selectors* respond.**

I can not find any reference for how this is done.

How can I connect to the back-end at store initialization?

**UPDATE Solution:**

So based on advice here from @dfil and @Clouse24 I Implemented `APP_INITIALIZER` for the convenience of it and that is where I wanted things to wire up.  And I updated my guard as follows:

Selectors:

```
export interface LoginStatus {
  loginChecked: boolean;
  loggedIn: boolean;
}
export const loginStatus = createSelector(
  selectAccount,
  account => ({ loginChecked: account.loginChecked, loggedIn: account.loggedIn }) as LoginStatus
);
```

The interface is just for types on the return (not to be confused with my AccountState).  I am tracking to see if the login was checked `loginChecked`, this is updated after  success or a fail or error. The `loggedIn` property is false until success.

My Guard:

```
 return this.store
      .pipe(
        select(loginStatus),
        filter(status => status.loginChecked),
        map(status => status.loggedIn),
        tap(loggedIn => {
          if (!loggedIn) {
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
          }
        }),
        take(1)
      );
```

All working fine and as expected. If you see any noticeable problems or improvements, fire away.

Comment: I think this may be more of a problem with your guard than when your action is called. You can have guards that effectively wait for a condition to be true rather than determining something is false and stopping the navigation altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use APP_INITIALIZER to get your data from store and dispatch action.

```js
 export function appInitializerFactory(
    localStorageService: LocalStorageService,
    store: Store<AuthState>
) {
    return () => {
        const auth = localStorageService.tryGetItem('auth') as Authenticated;
        if (auth) {
            store.dispatch(new Login(auth));
        }
    };
}
 
 
 providers:[
 {
       provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
       useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
       deps: [LocalStorageService, Store],
       multi: true
}
]
```

the second option is to make a guard that waits for the store to be initialized.